# Lua problems with variables

Tags: variables, lua

I wrote a Lua code to arrange a list but when I enter any number with 2 decimals as 10, 20, etc. in the list, the variable 'ordenado' always takes the value 1 although whether it fulfills the conditions or not.

```
valor = {}
ordenado = 0

function inicializar ()
  for i = 1,10 do
    print ("Introduzca el valor "..i..":")
    valor[i] = io.read()  
  end 
end

function verificar ()
  for i = 2, #valor do
    if valor[i]>valor[i-1] then
      ordenado = ordenado + 0
    else
      ordenado = ordenado + 1
    end
    print ("actual: "..valor[i].." \nanterior: "..valor[i-1].."\nordenado:"..ordenado.."\n")
  end
end

function imprimir()
  if ordenado == 0 then
    print "La lista esta ordenada"
  else 
    print "La lista no esta ordenada"
  end
end

a = inicializar()
a = verificar()
a = imprimir()
```

The Lua version is 5.2.

Comment: What do you intend with a statement like `ordenado = ordenado + 0`?

Comment: Use `valor[i] = tonumber(io.read())` to get numbers, not strings

Comment: faranwath: It is because the next function if the list is arranged then ordenado only take the value 0 and the program print that the list is arrenged. Sorry to write the code in Spanish

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Skriptunoff: you right, with this `valor[i] = tonumber(io.read())` it work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `valor[i] = io.read()` stores a *string* in `valor[i]`. As strings, `"2" > "10"`.

Comment: Won't I have this problem if I write `valor[i] = tonumber(io.read())`?

Comment: @Dominuskernel, probably not. Try it.